# How to create an array/slice of 5 value, all of same value

Tags: arrays, go

**Problem**

In go programming language, how to create an array of length 5, with all elements has same value, eg, 42.

**Preference order**

readability, conciseness, performance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := make([]int, 5)
    for i := range s {
        s[i] = 42
    }
    fmt.Println(len(s), s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/GjTXruMsJ5h

Output:

```
5 [42 42 42 42 42]
```

---

Some benchmarks:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkStack(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        s := make([]int, 5)
        for i := range s {
            s[i] = 42
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkHeap(b *testing.B) {
    var s []int
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        s = make([]int, 5)
        for i := range s {
            s[i] = 42
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkHygull(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        var s []int
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            s = append(s, 42)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test slice42_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkStack-8     1000000000      2.05 ns/op     0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkHeap-8       100000000     26.9 ns/op     48 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkHygull-8      10000000    123 ns/op      120 B/op    4 allocs/op
$
```

`BenchmarkHygull` demonstrates how inefficient @hygull's solution is.

---

A "one-liner":

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func newInts(n, v int) []int {
    s := make([]int, n)
    for i := range s {
        s[i] = v
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := newInts(5, 42)
    fmt.Println(len(s), s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/t8J-AjYQ72l

Output:

```
5 [42 42 42 42 42]
```

Comment: thx for your answer. I am new to golang, and currently this is exactly who I do in my code. Is there one-liner? Or I have to write it this way?

Comment: For benchmark code, there is a confusion, why two `make` in `BenchmarkHeap`? Also looks like looping through do assigning is the best I can get, since in most case, I won't bother to create a wrapper. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The first `make` is not essential so I replaced it with `var s []int`. I'm forcing a heap allocation.

Comment: For array/slice type, is my below understanding correct? slice : `var s []int`,
slice : `s := make(int, 5)`, array: `var s [5]int`. And array is of fixed length,
where slice is dynamic has `ptr, length, capacity` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

A generic way to do this is given below. It is only valid in go version 1.18 or higher

```golang
func RepeatedSlice[T any](elem T, size int) []T {
    s := make([]T, size)

    for i := range s {
        s[i] = elem
    }

    return s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do will be to use slice for that as it can grow dynamically.

Currently, you are looking only for **5** values so using arrays also is not a problem but what if you are looking for dynamic size (i.e. if you specify size of array in run time, there may be a chance of either going beyond the range or not using all the allocated spaces).

So I think the following code is sufficient to understand that.

```
package main  
import "fmt" 

func main() { 
    var s []int
    value := 42 // It can be changed to other values 

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        s = append(s, value)
    }

    fmt.Println(s); // [42 42 42 42 42]
}
```

Comment: Agree in most case it's sufficient to dynamic add item, just like C++ `std::vector` 's `.push_back`.

Comment: For a slice of known size, your solution is inefficient.